# Pandas: Help transforming data and writing better code

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sources I can join by a field and want to summarize them in a chart:

### Data

The two DataFrames share column `A`:

```py
ROWS = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': np.arange(ROWS),
                             'B': np.random.randint(0, 60, size=ROWS),
                             'C': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=ROWS)})
df.head()
```

```
   A   B   C
0  0  10  11
1  1   7  64
2  2  22  12
3  3   1  67
4  4  34  57
```

And `other` which I joined as such:

```py
other = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': np.arange(ROWS),
                                'D': np.random.choice(['One', 'Two'], ROWS)})
other.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df = df.join(other, on=['A'], rsuffix='_right')
df.head()
```

```
   A   B   C    D
0  0  10  11  One
1  1   7  64  Two
2  2  22  12  One
3  3   1  67  Two
4  4  34  57  One
```

### Question

A proper way to get a column chart with the count of:

- C is GTE50 and D is One
- C is GTE50 and D is Two
- C is LT50 and D is One
- C is LT50 and D is Two

Grouped by B, binned into 0, 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 21-40, 41+.

Comment: `df = df.merge(other)` would have done just as well.

Comment: @piRSquared, but `df.merge(other)` only works because they share the index. For it to work with real data `A` would need to be the index in both DataFrames, right?

Comment: `merge` merges on columns.  It can merge on indices if you tell it to but by default on columns.  If you don't specify which columns, it will choose columns that are common in both dataframes.  In this case, only column `'A'` is common to both and so it will merge on that.  Please see [@cs95's canonical on merging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/2336654)

Comment: @piRSquared I'm glad I posted the two DataFrames, I thought about posting the resulting and starting my question there, but I would have miss this learning. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, this can be dramatically simplified to a single groupby, taking advantage of `clip` and `np.ceil` to form your groups. A single unstack with 2 levels gives us the B-grouping as our x-axis with bars for each D-C combination:

If you want slightly nicer labels, you can map the `groupby` values:

```
(df.groupby(['D', 
             df.C.ge(50).map({True: 'GE50', False: 'LT50'}),
             np.ceil(df.B.clip(lower=0, upper=41)/10).map({0: '0', 1: '1-10', 2: '11-20', 3: '21-30', 4: '31-40', 5: '41+'})
            ])
     .size().unstack([0,1]).plot.bar())
```

[image]

---

Also it's equivalent to group B on:

```
pd.cut(df['B'],
       bins=[-np.inf, 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, np.inf],
       right=False,
       labels=['0', '1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41+'])
```

Comment: I've learn so much from your post: I'm going to stick to `pd.cut`, it's built for that; using `np.ceil` and `clip` is very clever, almost too clever. I also like how you used `DataFrameGroupBy.size`. I'll give more time for other answers to come, but this is very good!

Comment: Yeah, clip and floor/ceil/integer division can be nice from time to time, but are fairly particular. I prefer `size` when you just want the group size, though it is different from `count`, which will ignore not include `null` values in the counts for columns.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived to this solution after days of grinding, going back and forth, but there are many things I consider code smells:

- `groupby` returns a sort-of pivot table and `melt`'s purpose is to unpivot data.
- The use of dummies for `Cx`, but not for `D`? Ultimately they are both categorical data with 2 options. After two days, when I got this first solution I needed a break before trying another branch that treat these two equally.
- `reset_index`, only to `set_index` lines later. Having to `sort_values` before `set_index`
- That last `summary.unstack().unstack()` reads like a big **hack**.

```py
# %% Cx
df['Cx'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: 'LT50' if x < 50 else 'GTE50')
df.head()

# %% Bins
df['B_binned'] = pd.cut(df['B'],
                        bins=[-np.inf, 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, np.inf],
                        right=False,
                        labels=['0', '1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41+'])
df.head()

# %% Dummies
s = df['D']
dummies = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)

df.head()

# %% Summary
summary = df.groupby(['B_binned', 'Cx']).agg({'One': 'sum', 'Two': 'sum'})

summary.reset_index(inplace=True)
summary = pd.melt(summary,
                  id_vars=['B_binned', 'Cx'],
                  value_vars=['One', 'Two'],
                  var_name='D',
                  value_name='count')
summary.sort_values(['B_binned', 'D', 'Cx'], inplace=True)
summary.set_index(['B_binned', 'D', 'Cx'], inplace=True)
summary

# %% Chart
summary.unstack().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: You might want to consider using `np.where` instead of your current `apply` implementation, and also looking for an alternative to `apply(pd.Series)` if you want an improvement in performance here

Comment: @yatu, thanks for the pointers. I want both more readability and better performance, so I'll look into those. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Something like `df.groupby(['B_binned', 'Cx','D'])['D'].count().unstack([1,2])`

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy

Using numpy arrays to count then construct the `DataFrame` to plot

```
labels = np.array(['0', '1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41+'])
ge_lbl = np.array(['GE50', 'LT50'])

u, d = np.unique(df.D.values, return_inverse=True)
bins = np.array([1, 11, 21, 31, 41]).searchsorted(df.B)
ltge = (df.C.values >= 50).astype(int)

shape = (len(u), len(labels), len(ge_lbl))
out = np.zeros(shape, int)
np.add.at(out, (d, bins, ltge), 1)

pd.concat({
    d_: pd.DataFrame(o, labels, ge_lbl)
    for d_, o in zip(u, out)
}, names=['Cx', 'D'], axis=1).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solutions I'll consider this an advance introduction to **Numpy**. It's a little harder to read than a solution using **pandas** more, but lots to learn from it!

Comment: Absolutely.  I'd not advise this over a more user friendly Pandas solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a different way of doing it.

```
df['Bins'] = np.where(df['B'].isin([0]), '0',
            np.where(df['B'].isin(range(1,11)), '1-10',
            np.where(df['B'].isin(range(11,21)), '11-20',
            np.where(df['B'].isin(range(21,31)), '21-30',
            np.where(df['B'].isin(range(31,40)), '31-40','41+')
            ))))

df['Class_type'] = np.where(((df['C']>50) & (df['D']== 'One') ), 'C is GTE50 and D is One',
            np.where(((df['C']>50) & (df['D']== 'Two')) , 'C is GTE50 and D is Two',
            np.where(((df['C']<50) & (df['D']== 'One') ), 'C is LT50 and D is One',
                     'C is LT50 and D is Two')
            ))


df.groupby(['Bins', 'Class_type'])['C'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

#### Output ####
```

[image]

**WARNING:** Not sure how optimal the solution is.And also it consumes extra space so space complexity may increase.

Comment: In the case of many conditions, you can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to improve readability over several nested `np.where`. Also since the values are numeric I would use syntax like `df.B.between(1, 10)` as the condition

Comment: @Preetham I like the idea of being explicit about the "class" and having it on a column. @ALollz, `np.select` seems much better than the nested `np.where`.